# Angularfire2 - Is possible to update the data of firebase list by query?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire

Is angularfire2 can update multiple items by using queries instaed of item.$key

For example If I have this database tree

```
 Project
 --- items
 ------- {{key}}
 ------------ name: item1
 ------------ quantity : 0
 ------- {{key}}
 ------------ name: item2
 ------------ quantity : 0
 ------- {{key}}
 ------------ name: item3
 ------------ quantity : 12
```

I want to update the value of quantity for each item that contain 0 quantity to 30 such as this new database tree.

```
 Project
 --- items
 ------- {{key}}
 ------------ name: item1
 ------------ quantity : 30
 ------- {{key}}
 ------------ name: item2
 ------------ quantity : 30
 ------- {{key}}
 ------------ name: item3
 ------------ quantity : 12
```

Is that possible by using foreach or any other ways in Ionic 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update any of the *quantity* , you need the *key* of that particular item.
Say, the key of item1 in your example is '-KpZqM09AEDkhuIYAHSt' then in order to update the quantity of item1 you need the reference of

```
Project/items/-KpZqM09AEDkhuIYAHSt
```

So to update all those entry having quantity===0 to 30, you can do:

- Fetch all **items** using once() method of firebase with ref('items')
- iterate over the items using forEach and store the keys of all those items having quantity ===0 in an array. Use **.key** to get key of each item in items

  ```
  var keyArray = [];
  firebase.database().ref('items').once('value', data => {
      data.forEach(item => {
          if (item.val().qty === 0) {
              keyArray.push(item.key);
          }
      });
  });
  ```
- Once you get the keys, iterate over that key-array and for every key call firebase update() method with ref('items/'+keyOfItem)

  ```
  keyArray.forEach(keyOfItem => {
  firebase.database().ref('item/' + keyOfItem).update({
              quantity: 30
          });
  }
  //here keyOfItem is key of item having qty===0
  ```

  Don't forget that once() returns a promise which should be resolved first to get the second code working otherwise you will get keyArray as empty.
  *Hope you find this helpful.*